# 550 relay not permitted

Tags: email, webserver

I am on ubuntu 16.04.I have sent email to suggest business proposal.What I got in my gmail inbox was something like this

```
Your message couldn't be delivered to x.yd@xyz.com because the remote server is misconfigured. See the technical details below for more information.
```

Then

```
Final-Recipient: rfc822; xy@..com
Action: failed
Status: 5.0.0
Remote-MTA: dns; mailfilter1.mijndomein.nl. (5b00:4a40:1:1::9:3, the server
 for the domain xzy.com.)
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550 relay not permitted
Last-Attempt-Date: Tue, 26 Sep 2017 02:31:07 -0700 (PDT)
```

I have googled and it seems that his server treats my email(gmail) like a spam.How to avoid this?
EDIT
I have emailed my friend, no problem.
I have sent new mail to that guy in Nederlands,again comes mailer-daemon@googlemail.com notification.I can put the original content, but that is a private server.

Comment: What server do you use to send email? It's you local server or it public service (like gmail.com)?

Comment: from what I see I would rather say that it is not the server refusing your gmail.com, but instead you are trying to use their smtp server to send the email and since you are not a user of their email system, it refuses to do so. sending email using gmail smtp server would not produce such an error...

Comment: ... or may be you are not authenticating yourself properly with the gmail smtp server.

Comment: Could you mask the data **consistently**?

Comment: @EgorVasilyev I am using gmail.com(regarding the server,SBB Serbian internet provider)

Comment: @MikiBelavista see my answer below: you need to type login and password correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you try to send email via remote public email server**:

I think you have problem with local email client. Perhaps you forget to type login and password and you client try to send email without authentication.

Remote email server think that you are trying to use it as open relay and prevent this action.

---

If you are using wellknown public server there is nothing wrong with telling us his name. And we can check all needed DNS records

---

**If you try to use some private server**:

Possibly this server not yet configured to handling domain which you type in your email address.

Comment: Take a look at my edit.

Comment: @MikiBelavista try to send email from a different server (not gmail.com.) Perhaps you have another one's own email address. If you get the same error - the problem is on receiving server

Comment: Ok,will try for sure.

Comment: Great! And after this complete the post with new "debug" info. Thx